# Unable to install sklearn on macOS

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

Hi i've trie to install sklearn on macOS but i'm getting an error :

```
error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DUSE_VENDOR_BLAS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC -I/private/var/folders/8x/7jm2njhs7wb7vny_wchsj_q80000gn/T/pip-build-env-95_yvt7g/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/clacon2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/clacon2.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/clacon2.o.d" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I'm using python 3.9 and pip 20.2.4 .

Answer (score -1):

According to your error, there is some problem in scipy

- Solution

  - try removing Scipy and again Reinstalling Scipy
- references

  - [Scipy Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/)
  - [recent releases](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases)
  - [Scipy Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/)